# How to add fragment on top of another fragment using navigation jetpack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to add a fragment on top of another fragment. But while using navigation jetpack, it seems like replacing the fragment not adding.

I actually want to display a pop-up page so both fragments could communicate with each other, which seems to work for old add fragment function, but recently our project has been replaced with navigation jetpack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the options would be to make your second fragment extend `DialogFragment` and add it to your navigation graph as a `<dialog>` and not a `<fragment>`. It will be automatically shown as a dialogue by navigation component.

Here is an example:

```
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/myPopupDialogFragment"
        android:name="project.package.name.MyDialogFragment"
        android:label="MyDialogFragment">
        <!-- add arguments if you wish -->
    </dialog>
```

You can make this dialogue to be presented fullscreen using a fullscreen theme or as bottom sheet using:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting dialog. I created a custom dialog and it worked for me.

Comment: @kunaljaiswal, you are welcome. Accept the answer if you think it has solved the issue, so others could find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me ->

```
    fun ShowDialog()
    {
        //Inflate the dialog with custom view
        val mDialogView = 
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_popup, null)
    
        //AlertDialogBuilder
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(mDialogView)

        //show dialog
        val alertDialog=mBuilder.show()

        mDialogView.button_close.setOnClickListener {
           alertDialog.dismiss()
        }

        mDialogView.button_submit.setOnClickListener {
           viewModel.data.value="Data"
           alertDialog.dismiss()
       }
   }
```

So, instead of adding the fragment and communicating with it, we can add a dialog instead and add a listener to the views.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog->

```
    class ConfirmationDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
    val viewModelProvider =
      ViewModelProvider(navController.getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.nav_graph))
    val vm = viewModelProvider.get(GraphViewModel::class.java)

    return AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
      .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
      .setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_positive) { _, _ -> vm.onAccept() }
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_negative) { _, _ -> vm.onDecline() }
      .setOnCancelListener { vm.onDecline() }
      .create()
  }
```

Navigation->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
  app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.dialog.MainFragment"
    android:label="MainFragment" >
    <action
      android:id="@+id/confirmNuke"
      app:destination="@id/confirmationDialogFragment" />
  </fragment>
  <dialog
    android:id="@+id/confirmationDialogFragment"
    android:name="com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.dialog.ConfirmationDialogFragment"
    android:label="ConfirmationDialogFragment" />
</navigation>
```

Main fragment->

```
binding.nuke.setOnClickListener(v ->
      NavHostFragment.findNavController(MainFragment.this)
        .navigate(R.id.confirmNuke));
```